# Developing an application to restart another application

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, win32-process

I need to write an application which will be installed inside a windows7 embedded enterprise O/S. This applications job is to restart another application at a pre-configured time each day. Can you please tell me which API's do i need to refer for this purpose? Do i need to depend on the windows scheduler for this task? Is it possible to configure the scheduler from win32 code?

Is there any application which does this job already exist in the market?

Thanks,
John.

Comment: Yes. Windows Task Scheduler, which is built in to the OS and is designed to do this (among other things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from a batch file.

First, prepare a script, e.g. "restart.bat" to kill the process and restart it, killing can be done by [taskkill](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/446/xp_kill_windows_process_command_line_taskkill/), restarting should be done by [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to not block current script.

Then create setup batch file to add "restart.bat" to [task scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc738335(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I would use a Task Scheduler which is good documented and has many examples.
Take a look at [Time Trigger Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> This C++ example shows how to create a task that is scheduled to
>   execute Notepad at a specified time. The task contains a time-based
>   trigger that specifies a start boundary and an end boundary for the
>   task. The task also contains an action that specifies the task to
>   execute Notepad. The task is registered using an interactive logon
>   type, which means the task runs under the security context of the user
>   who runs the application. The task also contains idle settings, which
>   specifies how Task Scheduler performs tasks when the computer is in an
>   idle condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can get (or specify as a string) the PID from [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28VS.85%29.aspx), kill the process using [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28VS.85%29.aspx)() and then later you can create process by [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx)() function from Win32.

Another approach is that you can also use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)() or [system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4b6wz4t.aspx) to executed commandline commands directely from a Visual C++ program, and pass a command as:

```
taskkill /F /T /IM MyProcess.exe
```

later simply open the application using `ShellExecute` or `system`.